# Jquery Generically, show/Hide division within division in Yes/No Radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically, I wanted to show/hide the div by clicking Yes/No Radio button. I have also done a sample types in the fiddle link below. I want to make this Generic, like one function can do for all the yes/no questions. and i want to avoid the multiple if condtion in jquery.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="well well-sm">
        <label class="control-label">1) Are you a Student??</label>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="student" id="studentYes" value="yes"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="student" id="studentNo" value="no"> No
            </label>
        </div>

        <div id="stdTypes" class="studentsType">

            <label class="control-label">1.1) Are you a Graduate Student?</label>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="gradstd" id="gradstd1" value="yes"> Yes
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="gradstd" id="gradstd2" value="no"> No
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="departName">
                <label class="control-label">1.2) Please Enter your Department?</label>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="well well-sm">
        <label class="control-label">2) Are you earning for your living?</label>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="living" value="yes"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="living"  value="no"> No
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="earning">

            <label class="control-label">2.1) How much do you earn?</label>
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" />
            </div>

        </div>



    </div>
```

My jquery look this.

```
$('input[name="student"]:radio').change(function () {
    var radio_value = ($('input:radio[name="student"]:checked').val());
    if (radio_value == 'yes') {
        $('.studentsType').slideDown("fast");
    }
    else if (radio_value == 'no') {
        $('.studentsType').slideUp("fast");
    }
});

$('input[name="gradstd"]:radio').change(function () {
    var radio_value = ($('input:radio[name="gradstd"]:checked').val());
    if (radio_value == 'yes') {
        $('.departName').slideDown("fast");
    }
    else if (radio_value == 'no') {
        $('.departName').slideUp("fast");
    }
});
$('input[name="living"]:radio').change(function () {
    var radio_value = ($('input:radio[name="living"]:checked').val());
    if (radio_value == 'yes') {
        $('.earning').slideDown("fast");
    }
    else if (radio_value == 'no') {
        $('.earning').slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Links for Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mgrgfqfd/

Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `data` attribute in the radio buttons to indicate which DIV should be toggled.

```js
$(':radio[data-rel]').change(function() {
  var rel = $("." + $(this).data('rel'));
  if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
    rel.slideDown();
  } else {
    rel.slideUp();
    rel.find(":text,select").val("");
    rel.find(":radio,:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```css
.studentsType,
.departName,
.earning {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <label class="control-label">1) Are you a Student??</label>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="student" id="studentYes" value="yes" data-rel="studentsType">Yes
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="student" id="studentNo" value="no" data-rel="studentsType">No
          </label>
        </div>

        <div id="stdTypes" class="studentsType">

          <label class="control-label">1.1) Are you a Graduate Student?</label>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="gradstd" id="gradstd1" value="yes" data-rel="departName">Yes
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="gradstd" id="gradstd2" value="no" data-rel="departName">No
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="departName">
            <label class="control-label">1.2) Please Enter your Department?</label>
            <div class="control-group">
              <input type="text" />
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <label class="control-label">2) Are you earning for your living?</label>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="living" value="yes" data-rel="earning">Yes
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="living" value="no" data-rel="earning">No
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="earning">

          <label class="control-label">2.1) How much do you earn?</label>
          <div class="control-group">
            <input type="text" />
          </div>

        </div>



      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel footer</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please suggest !! how can i remove all the data if N0 is selected again in radio button !!

Comment: You mean clear the input fields in the DIV that you close? Add `rel.find('input').val('')`

Comment: if i close the divison selecting 'No', It clear the input text field, but it didn't clear the radio button, and again on same radio button if it is selected 'Yes', the input text box is not opened.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It should just empty the value of text inputs, it should remove the "checked" property from checkboxes and radio buttons.

Comment: incase if div is opened and the form is submitted. but radio button or input field is empty or unchecked. How could i validate that the radio button and input box should be checked.

Comment: You can add the `required` attribute when opening the DIV, and remove it when closing the DIV. How to do that is an exercise for the reader -- step up and be a real programmer, not a help vampire.

Comment: please !! Explanation would be very helpful i had tried a lot and search a lot but it didn't work as per my requirement.

Comment: To make elements required, use `$(selector).attr('required', true)`. To make them not required, use `$(elements).attr('required', false)`. Do that at the same time that you clear them when sliding up and down.

Comment: You really need to learn how things work and think for yourself, you can't expect everything to be spoon-fed to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep this sort of structure it can be achieved with a tiny bit of code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mgrgfqfd/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <label class="control-label">1) Are you a Student??</label>

            <div class="control-group" data-target="gruduate">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="student" value="yes"> Yes
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="student" value="no"> No
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="optional">

                <label class="control-label">1.1) Are you a Graduate Student?</label>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="gradstd" id="gradstd1" value="yes"> Yes
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="gradstd" id="gradstd2" value="no"> No
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="optional">
                    <label class="control-label">1.2) Please Enter your Department?</label>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <input type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="well well-sm">
            <label class="control-label">2) Are you earning for your living?</label>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="living" value="yes"> Yes
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="living"  value="no"> No
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="optional">

                <label class="control-label">2.1) How much do you earn?</label>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel footer</div>
</div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input:radio').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parents('.control-group').next('div.optional').toggle( $(this).val() == 'yes' );
});
```

Just ensure that your yes/no buttons are within a control-group and you put the optional elements directly after it inside a div with a class of .optional

Comment: Please suggest !! how can i remove all the data if  **N0** is selected again in radio button !!

Comment: @aakash I'm not sure what you mean by "remove all the data"

Comment: Suppose in Question 1, at first....If i click 'yes' and fill all the toggled form, but again i don't like to fill the form and  i click 'no', now all the data entered in question 1 should be removed.

Comment: @aakash I'm not sure if removing the checked attribute from your radio buttons all together is a good idea, radio buttons are supposed to have one required option - you could toggle the disabled attribute on them to stop them passing data back to your server when the form is submitted.

Comment: parent's questions should remain either yes/no they should not be empty, but answer on child questions should be erased if parent questions have the answer 'NO'. The value of the Radio buttons and input text both should be erased on child questions.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will find next div and perform sliding in jquery this helps you to avoid multiple redundant lines of code and ifs.

```
$('input:radio').on('change', function () {//Register change event for all radio button                
            if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {//check value of selected radio is yes
                $(this).parent().parent().next('div').slideDown("fast");
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == 'no') {//check value of selected radio is no
                $(this).parent().parent().next('div').slideUp("fast");
            }

        });
```